# Is there a name for the ending year of an era?

Tags: words, word-requests

[元]{がん}[年]{ねん} is a term for the first year of an era, i. e. 平成元年=1989 starting with 8 January. But what is the term of the ending one, i. e. 2019 for Heisei?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the phrase is 末年{まつねん}.

According to [Goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/208821/meaning/m0u/):

> １ 人生またはある時代の終わりのころ。また、最後の年。ばつねん。「昭和の末年」

It can be used without the の as well. However, it seems that this phrasing isn't common and both 昭和64年 and 平成元年 are much more common